# Infer key type from value of object in function overload signature

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

I have a function I defined for mapping values of an iterable, very similar to `Array.prototype.map()`, but I've simplified it for this example to basically be equivalent, since those details are irrelevant:

```
function select <T, U> (array: T[], selectFn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: unknown): U[] {
  return array.map(selectKeyOrFn, thisArg);
}

select(['foo', 'bar'], s => s.length);
```

So far, so good. Everything compiles. Now I want to accept either a function, or a `keyof T` for the second argument. I'm not sure how best to define the type parameters for this overload signature, but here was my failed approach:

```
type KeyOfValue<T, U extends T[keyof T]> = U extends T[infer K] ? K : never;

function select <T, U extends T[keyof T]> (array: T[], selectKey: KeyOfValue<T, U>): U[]
function select <T, U> (array: T[], selectFn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: unknown): U[]
function select <T, U> (array: T[], selectKeyOrFn: (U extends T[keyof T] ? KeyOfValue<T, U> : never) | ((value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U), thisArg?: unknown): U[] {
  return typeof selectKeyOrFn === 'function'
    ? array.map(selectKeyOrFn, thisArg)
    : array.map(value => value[selectKeyOrFn]);
}

select(['foo', 'bar'], 'length');
select(['foo', 'bar'], s => s.length);
```

The main issue seems to be that my `KeyOfValue` type doesn't allow the syntax I'm trying to use to `infer K` as an index of `T`:

> Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

How can I successfully prototype this overload function? I'd prefer not to resort to a helper type like `KeyOfValue`, but at the moment I can't think of a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things here with conditional types. Habing a type parameter for the key and using a type query will work better. Also for the implementation signature you can have an amalgamation of the two overloaded signatures no need to use the same `U` as a return type:

```
function select <T, K extends keyof T> (array: T[], selectKey: K): T[K][]
function select <T, U> (array: T[], selectFn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: unknown): U[]
function select <T, U, K extends keyof T> (array: T[], selectKeyOrFn: K | ((value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U), thisArg?: unknown): T[K][] | U[] {
  return typeof selectKeyOrFn === 'function'
    ? array.map(selectKeyOrFn, thisArg)
    : array.map(value => value[selectKeyOrFn]);
}

select(['foo', 'bar'], 'length');
select(['foo', 'bar'], s => s.length);
```

Comment: I was not aware that the type parameters of the union signature could work like that! Thank you so much.